# Cannot retrieve Card URL from Trello PowerUp

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, trello, trello-powerup

i am trying to get the current Card url from my Powerup iframe JS code, but i get "undefined" , when calling `t.card().url`

Please can you check what is wrong with my code?
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://p.trellocdn.com/power-up.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var GRAY_ICON = 'https://cdn.hyperdev.com/us-east-1%3A3d31b21c-01a0-4da2-8827-4bc6e88b7618%2Ficon-gray.svg';

        TrelloPowerUp.initialize({
            'card-buttons': function (t, options) { // Card buttons
                return [
                    {
                        icon: "https://cdn.hyperdev.com/us-east-1%3A3d31b21c-01a0-4da2-8827-4bc6e88b7618%2Ficon-gray.svg", // Set trial lesson button
                        text: "Set Trial Lesson",
                        callback: function (t) {
                            var mentorName = window.prompt("Enter Mentor Name:");
                            if (mentorName !== null) {
                                var topic = window.prompt("Enter Topic/s to focus (leave blank if nothing special):");

                                var cardUrl = t.card().url;
                                var url = `https://somewebsite.com/api.php?action=set_trial_lesson&card_url=${encodeURIComponent(cardUrl)}&mentor_name=${encodeURIComponent(mentorName)}&topic=${encodeURIComponent(topic)}`;

                                // Make a GET request to the API endpoint
                                fetch(url, {
                                    method: 'GET'
                                })
                                    .then(function (response) {
                                        if (response.ok) {
                                            return response.json();
                                        } else {
                                            throw new Error('Failed to create trial lesson. Please try again.');
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .then(function (data) {
                                        if (data.status === 'success') {
                                            throw { success: true, message: 'Trial lesson created successfully!' };
                                        } else if (data.status === 'error') {
                                            throw { success: false, message: data.message };
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .catch(function (UserMessage) {
                                        var displayType = UserMessage.success ? 'success' : 'error';
                                        var successMessage = UserMessage.success ? '✓ ' + UserMessage.message : UserMessage.message;
                                        var errorMessage = UserMessage.success ? UserMessage.message : '✗ ' + UserMessage.message;

                                        t.alert({
                                            message: UserMessage.success ? successMessage : errorMessage,
                                            display: displayType,
                                            duration: 5 // Adjust the duration to control how long the message is displayed
                                        });
                                    });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        icon: "https://cdn.hyperdev.com/us-east-1%3A3d31b21c-01a0-4da2-8827-4bc6e88b7618%2Ficon-gray.svg", // Iframe Websites
                        text: "Iframe Websites",
                        callback: function (t) {
                            return t.popup({
                                title: "Menu",
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        text: "Respond.io",
                                        callback: function (t) {
                                            return t.popup({
                                                title: "Respond.io",
                                                items: [
                                                    {
                                                        text: "Update Iframe",
                                                        callback: function (t, opts) {
                                                            if (respondLink) {
                                                                t.set('card', 'shared', 'webSectionContentUrl', respondLink)
                                                                    .then(function () {
                                                                        t.get('board', 'private', 'cardBackRefreshed', false)
                                                                            .then(function (cardBackRefreshed) {
                                                                                t.set('board', 'private', 'cardBackRefreshed', !cardBackRefreshed)
                                                                                    .then(function () {
                                                                                        t.closePopup();
                                                                                    });
                                                                            });
                                                                    });
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        text: "Set URL",
                                                        callback: function (t, opts) {
                                                            respondLink = window.prompt("Enter the new URL for the Respond.io:");
                                                            t.closePopup();
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        text: "Cancel",
                                                        callback: function (t) {
                                                            return t.closePopup();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            });
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: "Lesson status",
                                        callback: function (t, opts) {
                                            var cardUrl = t.card().url;
                                            if (cardUrl) {
                                                var trialLessonLink = `https://somewebsite.com/api.php?action=get_lesson_status&card_url=${encodeURIComponent(cardUrl)}`;

                                                t.set('card', 'shared', 'webSectionContentUrl', trialLessonLink)
                                                    .then(function () {
                                                        t.get('board', 'private', 'cardBackRefreshed', false)
                                                            .then(function (cardBackRefreshed) {
                                                                t.set('board', 'private', 'cardBackRefreshed', !cardBackRefreshed)
                                                                    .then(function () {
                                                                        t.closePopup();
                                                                    });
                                                            });
                                                    });
                                            } else {                                               
                                                console.log("Card URL is undefined");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            });
                        }
                    }
                ];
            },
            'card-back-section': function (t, options) { // Iframe
                return t.get('card', 'shared', 'webSectionContentUrl')
                .then(function (webSectionContentUrl) {
                    if (!webSectionContentUrl) {
                       webSectionContentUrl = 'https://example.com/';
                    }
                    return {
                       title: 'iframe URL:',
                       icon: GRAY_ICON,
                       content: {
                           type: 'iframe',
                           url: webSectionContentUrl,
                           height: 800,
                       },
                       action: {
                           text: 'Custom Link',
                           callback: function (t) {
                               var newUrl = window.prompt('Enter URL:');
                               if (newUrl) {
                                   t.set('card', 'shared', 'webSectionContentUrl', newUrl);
                                   return t.closePopup();
                               }
                           }
                       }
                    };
                });
            },
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

ADDENDUM: i would want to just get `top.location.href` to retrieve the current url, but it fails since the powerup iframe is from another domain, so the browser won't let me access `top.location.href` (cross origin policies)